# How do I return the day of the week, then return the name of week from the Weather API?

Tags: python, weather-api

```
def getForecast():

    zip2 = '60103'

    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=' \
      '' + zip2 + 
         ',us&appid=7f5941b864a5fde449419c6aaca23540&units=imperial'.format(zip2)

    response = requests.get(url)
    data2 = response.json()  

    date_list = (data2['list'][0]['dt_txt'])
    date_list = date_list.split()
    del date_list[-1]
    new = list(date_list[0].split('-'))
    new1 = [int(x) for x in new]


    print(calendar.weekday(new1))
```

According to the calendar doc, "new1" should be in the correct format to return the day of the week, but I receive an error: "`weekday() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'month' and 'day'`" When I manually insert the year, month, day, I receive the day of the week just fine.

Comment: Weekday is expecting two arguments. You have given 1. What is new1? Printing its value (and updating your question) will help.

Answer (score 1):

[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday), you need to give 3 parameters, `year, month, day` to `weekday` function, but you give a `list`, your `new1` is of type `list` try something like this

```
import calendar

# if you have a list with year, month, day
# for example this
new1 = [2018, 6, 19]

print(calendar.weekday(*new1)) # important to put * before new1

# output
# 1
```